# Maven: custom assembly deployment

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Due to need for heavy customization I did developed my own Groovy plugin, which creates ZIP archive, which is 100% ready for deployment (like Maven assembly plugin does). Still, if I run

`mvn clean install ...`

command it creates an assembly (single ZIP file), puts it to ${project.build.directory} (.../target) and that's it.

How do I tell Maven, that it's now part of deployment and I would like to deploy this ZIP file?

Comment: No, it's not the issue! Problem is that plugin generates ZIP file, but Maven don't know that this file has something to do with deployment goal. I can't find it copied to my local repo either.

Comment: can you share your `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin section from you `pom.xml` ? I am curious to see how you are specifying your assembly.xml and whatnot

Comment: You did something with configuration of maven-assembly-plugin cause by default the generated zip archives are attached to the project. So without your pom it's hard to say what's wrong. The build-helper-plugin is the wrong way.

Comment: maven-assembly-plugin is NOT USED AT ALL. It's my custom plugin which do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Use [buildhelper:attach-artifact](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifacts>
            <artifact>
              <file>some file</file>
              <type>extension of your file </type>
              <classifier>optional</classifier>
            </artifact>
            ...
          </artifacts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Alternatively (and better), you could include the necessary code in your own plugin:

```
@Component
protected MavenProject project;

@Component
protected MavenProjectHelper projectHelper;

...

projectHelper.attachArtifact(project, "jar", resource.getClassifier(), targetArchive);
```

Comment: Thanks, first approach worked fine! Unfortunatelly I wasn't able to embed it in my plugin, because I am using groovy-maven-plugin and invoking attachArtifact from Groovy code showed no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it worked in Groovy too (running from groovy-maven-plugin):

```
def helper =
        session.lookup("org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectHelper");

helper.attachArtifact(project, "zip", _classifier, new File(_archiveFilename));
```

N.B.:

Both _classifier and _archiveFilename should be declared and initialized by your code.